# Sort records based on two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have `Task` table and I want to sort the records based on 2 of its columns named `owner` and `task_type`. Remember that I do not want a tie-breaking based sorting between these two columns, instead what I want is that the values of these 2 columns act as a single list of values(for the sorting) on which the sorting will be applied. 
Is it even possible? I'm using ActiveRecord with Postgresql.
For example if I have these 3 records:

1. (id: 1, owner: 'abc', task_type: null)
2. (id: 2, owner: null, task_type:'aa')
3. (id: 1, owner: 'abe',task_type:'null')

I want the sorting to be done on these values

```
('abc','null','null', 'aa', 'abe', 'null')
```

Which will sort them in this order (I need to achieve this)

1. (id: 2, owner: null, task_type:'aa')
2. (id: 1, owner: 'abc', task_type: null)
3. (id: 1, owner: 'abe', task_type:'null')

Note I am assuming the `owner` and the `task_type` are exclusive fields(i.e if one has value the other will be null) 
I have tested this and it only sorts the records on tie-breaking principle.

```
Task.order(owner: :asc, task_type: :asc)
```

This code sorts them in this order (I do not want this)

1. (id: 1, owner: 'abc', task_type: null)
2. (id: 1, owner: 'abe', task_type:'null')
3. (id: 2, owner: null, task_type:'aa')

Comment: Looks like you want to sort on `COALESCE(owner, task_type)`. I don't know much about rails, maybe try `Task.order("coalesce(owner, task_type)")`?

Comment: thanks Marth that seems to work